# Formula with indices

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, tensor-calculus

Does anyone recognize this as something familiar?

$\epsilon^{acm}\partial_m\Theta^{kb}+\frac12\epsilon^{abm}\partial_m\Theta^{kc}$

OR

$(\epsilon^{acm}\partial_m\Theta^{kb}
+\frac12\epsilon^{abm}\partial_m\Theta^{kc})\big(A_i\partial_bB_j +B_i  \partial_b A_j \big)$

Comment: Could you give us some more context, please?

Comment: What is $\Theta$?  Is it a 2-form or symmetric or no symmetry at all?

Comment: $\Theta$ is the function coefficient of a Poisson bracket